# How come a pointer to a derived class cannot be passed to a function expecting a reference to a pointer to the base class?

Tags: c++

Sorry for the long title but I did want to be specific.
I expected the following code to work but it doesn't and I can't figure out why :/

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

class UniquePointer
{
public:
    void Dispose()
    {
        delete this;
    }

    friend void SafeDispose(UniquePointer*& p)
    {
        if (p != NULL)
        {
            p->Dispose();
            p = NULL;
        }
    }
protected:
    UniquePointer() { }
    UniquePointer(const UniquePointer&) { }
    virtual ~UniquePointer() { }
};

class Building : public UniquePointer
{
public:
    Building()
    : mType(0)
    {}
    void SetBuildingType(int type) { mType = type; }
    int GetBuildingType() const { return mType; }
protected:
    virtual ~Building() { }
    int mType;
};

void Foo()
{
    Building* b = new Building();
    b->SetBuildingType(5);
    int a = b->GetBuildingType();
    SafeDispose(b);     // error C2664: 'SafeDispose' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Building *' to 'UniquePointer *&'
    b->Dispose();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that there is nothing "safe" about what you are trying to do. If `b` is set to `NULL` then `b->Dispose();` causes behaviour that is just as undefined as if `b` pointed to a deleted object.

Comment: @Charles: Edited, waiting for review. This bug is not a part of a question, is it?

Comment: Also, no need for `SafeDispose` to be a friend since `Dispose` is public.

Comment: The real answer is that the `Building` is a subclass of `UniquePointer` but the `Building*` is a subclass of `UniquePointer*`. That's why you can't cast `Building*` to `UniquePointer*&` - it's not a polymorphism.

Comment: @Charles: Yeah wasn't meant to be safe, it was just me experimenting with the language :) I wanted to know how systems like COM are implemented so I started off with a simple unique pointer, then later on I would have moved to a reference counting system.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Imagine it were legal. Then you could write code like this:

```
class Animal : public UniquePointer
{
};

void Transmogrify(UniquePointer*& p)
{
    p = new Animal();
}

void Foo()
{
    Building* b = nullptr;
    Transmogrify(b);
    b->SetBuildingType(0); // crash
}
```

Observe that you have violated the type system (you put an Animal where a Building should be) without requiring a cast or raising a compiler error.

Comment: I see your point. The reason I wanted the reference to pointer was to be able to set that pointer to NULL but I obviously missed out all the side effects this could have.

Answer (score 6):

I do not think that it is possible to make it work the way you have it designed. Instead, try the following:

```
template <typename T>
void SafeDispose(T * & p)
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        p->Dispose();
        p = NULL;
    }
}

class UniquePointer
{
public:
    void Dispose()
    {
        delete this;
    }

protected:
    UniquePointer() { }
    UniquePointer(const UniquePointer&) { }
    virtual ~UniquePointer() { }
};
```

Comment: I like your solution, in fact should you have told why it is not possible to do it the way I did it this would have been my accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is not allowed because if it were you could do the following:

```
friend void SafeDispose(UniquePointer*& p)
{
    p = new UniquePointer();   
}


Building* building;
SafeDispose(building)
//building points to a UniquePointer not a Building.
```

I guess the work around would be a template function.

Comment: Except that you cannot instantiate unique pointer, it must be subclassed. But I do see your point.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the title of your question, you cannot bind a non-const reference to base to a derived class instance because you could then set that reference to a pointer to a base instance that isn't a derived. Consider this function:

```
void Renew(UniquePointer *& p) {
  delete p;
  p = new UniquePointer();
}
```

if you could pass it a pointer to `Building` you would be able to set it incorrectly to point to a `UniquePointer` instance.

As it has already been suggested the solution is to change your reference to a plain pointer. Not only this solves your problem, but it is also a better implementation of `SafeDispose()`; as you wrote it this function gave the false idea that you would always set to 0 all your `UniquePointer` instances. But what would happen if somebody wrote (assuming `UniquePointer` constructor was public for simplicity):

```
UniquePointer *p1 = new UniquePointer();
UniquePointer *p2 = p1;
SafeDispose(p1);
```

They would expect all of their `UniquePointer`s to be properly taken care of, when `p2` is actually invalid.

Comment: I could have probably given everything a better name than what I did. I intended SafeDispose to set the pointer to NULL and check for NULL, but I didn't consider the fact that the callee could have a copy of the pointer. But it is important to note that there is no sharing whatsoever, I was interested in a "singe ownership" system after reading Google's coding style.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your SafeDispose should probably look more like :

```
friend void SafeDispose(UniquePointer** p) ...
```

In order to invoke it using

```
SafeDispose(&(UniquePointer*)b);
```

Then it should work this way.

But your next statement

```
b->Dispose();
```

will break cause b should now be NULL, cause it has been disposed and set to NULL by your SafeDispose method.

Comment: But `&b` is an rvalue of type `Building**` which you can't pass to a function taking a `UniquePointer**` for pretty much identical reasons that you can't bind a `Building*` to a non-const `UniquePointer*&`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Adding a cast would probably fix this issue right ?! (updated sample code).

Then I guess that wilx answer (by using a template) makes more sense.

Comment: No, a cast doesn't fix the issue it creates a new one. The cast converts the pointer but the result of the cast is an rvalue and you can't then take the address of an rvalue.