# C++, Need Reason for error : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'const char *&'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, reference

Whey we cannot Convert pointer to a character ->TO-> a reference to a pointer to a constant character

I am interested in knowing the reason of syntax error when we call foo_ptr. When foo_char is allowed why not foo_ptr.
[Update 1.] I would be happy in knowing the reason that `foo_char()` is working, why `foo_ptr()` is not working .. What happens when pointer come in the picture. 

[Update 2.]
Didnt work in Dev C++ compiler version 4.9.9.2 too ..

```
//code
//OS : Win XP
//Env: VC++ 2008 

//NOT ALLOWED
void foo_ptr(const char * & ptr) //reference to a pointer to a constant character         
{         
        return;         
}        


//allowed        
void foo_char(const char & p_Char) //reference to a constant character        
{         
        return;        
}        

int main()        
{        
        char ch = 'd';        
        char *ptr =  "anu";        

        foo_char(ch);         
        foo_ptr(ptr); //NOT ALLOWED syntax error, vc++, 2008        

        return 0;        
}
```

Comment: Maybe the parser is wrong, try `foo_ptr((const char *)& ptr`.

Comment: Everything compiled fine on VC2010. Maybe a fixed bug?

Comment: @RedX : Thanks for the inputs, void foo_ptr((const char * )& ptr) gave error C2065 : undeclared identified

Comment: @AtoMerZ: May be.. That sounds more reasonable.. Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: @AtoMerZ: Didnt work in Dev C++ compiler version 4.9.9.2 too .. by the way ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revised with more examples: 
 [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) provides the correct answer.  By passing a non const pointer (`char *`) as reference parameter of a const pointer (`foo_ptr(const char * &param)`)  you risk returning a const pointer type (`const char *`) and the compiler won't allow you to do that.

Here's  [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen)'s example of that, but I tried to explain how things would go wrong if it compiled by adding additional comments and code:

```
void foo_ptr(const char * & ptr)
{         
    //Valid assignment, and the char * is now pointing to a const
    //array of "readonlystring"
    ptr = "readonlystring";
}   

...
//inside main
char *ptr = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
//See you can edit ptr, it's not const.
ptr[0] = 'a';
ptr[1] = 'b';
//this should not compile, but lets assume it did..
foo_ptr(ptr);
//Oh no, now ptr[0] is 'r' inside of constant memory,
//but now since ptr isn't declared const here I can overwrite it!
//But luckily most (all?) compilers actually fail to compile this code.
ptr[0] = 'b';
```

But if you change your parameter so you can't affect the value that the pointer points to then the compiler will let you past in a non-const because there is no chance a const valued pointer is returned.

By placing the keyword `const` AFTER the `*` in your parameter deceleration you do just that. That means change:

```
void foo_ptr(const char * & ptr)
```

to

```
void foo_ptr(const char * const & ptr)
```

and your compiler will be happy.

Now you would not be able to do something like `ptr = "readonlystring"` in the above example because that would never compile now.  Based on your question that should be OK because you would not be able to do the assignment to a `const char &` in your original example.

Comment: Eric and @James : Thank you so much guys. To me, this sounds better than any other answered here [at least to my understaning]. I am novice and It would be really helpful if a bit detail in explaination with example(s) can be added here to help us understand this completely. (or any source/link would also work equally). .... I gave a lot of thought esp on the line "....const array pointer you risk returning a const pointer type".. but couldnt feel satisfied.. Thanks a lot for the time and effort.

Comment: I revised the answer with some more code and explanation. Hopefully the snippets I added to explain the line that confused you will help.

Comment: Great.. I now.. understood. Thanks a lot :). I appreciate the efforts and time you spent. Many thanks again.

Comment: [Update 3.]
My doubt is resolved. I am satisfied. Thanks to every one for their time and efforts in helping me. Esp. I would like to thank Raymond(who was right but I did not understand his point at the first time), Eric Z(Who added more values) and finally James who explained Eric's point with detailed example. Thanks a lot guys. 

James- Thanks for closing this post (at least from my side.).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why I thought it was Eric I was quoting, it was [Raymond Chen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen)

Answer (score 10):

Suppose you had

```
void foo_ptr(const char * & ptr)
{         
    ptr = "readonlystring";
}
```

You now call it as

```
    char *ptr;
    foo_ptr(ptr);
    *ptr = 0;
```

Suppose no error were raised. You are writing to a read-only string, violating the type system without any casts.

This is basically the CV version of [How come a pointer to a derived class cannot be passed to a function expecting a reference to a pointer to the base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186341/how-come-a-pointer-to-a-derived-class-cannot-be-passed-to-a-function-expecting-a).

Comment: Good point. But you can do that with `typedef char* CHARPTR` anyway already.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Changing `char *ptr` to `CHARPTR ptr` would still raise an error.

Comment: What's the error? Replacing `char*` w/ typedef in OP's code should compile successfully.

Comment: Oh, you mean replacing it in foo_ptr. That's because `const char *&` is not the same as `const CHARPTR&`. The former is a reference to a pointer to a `const char`. The latter is a const reference to a pointer to a `char`. So it's a different function.

Comment: I intend to write function only to read the value from reference to a pointer not to write into it. The concern is not on the application part, but to explore the behavior of C++. The error came as: error C2664: 'foo_ptr' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'const char *&'

Comment: C++ doesn't prevent such kind of mistakes. char* p= "blahblahblah"; p[0]=0; is legal (unfortunately)

Comment: @user976141, then what you really need is `char * const &` or `const char * const &`.

Comment: @EricZ :Thanks again, char * const &, I guess is not a reference to a pointer to a constant character, its close reference to a constant pointer. I guess I was little reserved while explaining. I would be happy in knowing the reason that foo_char() is working, why foo_ptr() is not working .. What happens when pointer come in the picture.

Comment: Sorry, the example in my previous comment is depricated. I agree with Raymond. Parameter, passing by reference is (potentially) output parameter, so the rules for the parameter(constness) must be the same as for function return value

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thanks again. Very much appreciable. I did not understand the comment. foo_ptr(const char * & ptr) : i guess is a reference to a pointer to a constant character. and foo_char() : reference to a constant character. At least, thats what I meant. Please let me know if the actual declaration syntax and my understanding of these declarations mismatched.

Comment: @anubhav16: oh, pointer is exactly the same. the parameter of `foo_char` is a reference to const char but the parameter of `foo_ptr` is not a reference to const pointer, it's a reference to pointer to const char. That's the point. If it were a reference to const pointer(as I did w/ typedef), it should work fine as `foo_char`.

Comment: +1: This is the correct answer.  Also, if you want to fix this to get the behavior you are expecting change the parameter to `const char * const & ptr`

Answer (score 0):

You should never assign a string literal to a non-`const` `char` pointer, as you do here:

```
 char *ptr =  "anu";
```

Change the above to correct code:

```
 const char *ptr =  "anu";
```

...and I think you'll find your problems are solved.

Comment: But that doesn't answer his question.

Comment: thanks for the time, but Yeah, that didnt answer my question. If 'const' had been the only concern , how did it work for foo_char ?